# Get coordinates of polygon outline and polygon mask given vertex coordinates

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

Given a matrix containing a polygon mask (here a small and simplistic case):

```py
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The outline is extracted with `skimage.segmentation.find_boundaries()`, giving:

```py
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The outline's `[row,column]` (i.e. `[y,x]`) coordinates are then extracted giving:

```py
outline = array([[2,2],[1,2],[1,3],[2,4],[3,5],[4,5],[5,4],[5,3],[5,2],[4,1],[3,1]])
```

These coordinates are then pruned to a minimal set that define the polygon (i.e. the vertices), giving:

```py
vertices = array([[2,2],[1,2],[1,3],[3,5],[4,5],[5,4],[5,2],[4,1],[3,1]])
```

(Which corresponds to:)

```py
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Is there a fast way using numpy/scipy/skimage/etc to get the outline coordinates (the array `outline` above) given the vertex coordinates (the array `vertices` above)?
Further, after getting back the outline coordinates, is there a good numpy/scipy/skimage way to get back the coordinates of all points in the original polygon mask?

Answer (score 1):

Given 2 vertices in a polygon `v1, v2` we can get all the points `p` which are part of the line from `v1` to `v2` using a line rasterization algorithm. A very fast algorithm for this is [Bresenham's line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). After this you can apply this algorithm for each pair of adject vertices in the polygon. Although, I can not guarantee that the outline will be exactly the one in the original polygon since the rasterization algorithm will give the best set of points for the given line, not the one you have in the original algorithm (consider them compression errors).

For the filling algorithm, they are called polygon rasterization algorithm, but I can't help you here since I don't know which are best/fastest.